# jupyter notebook not formatting text colour when calling print('\033[92m' + str)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The following line

```
print('\033[92m' + "Hello")
```

should change the font colour to green and print `Hello` and that's what happens when running the line in the terminal.

However, that's not what happens in the jupyter notebook: it prints `Hello` but without changing the colour: how can I make it work on jupyter notebook as well?

I am on Ubuntu and I ran the notebook from the Terminal. My jupyter notebook version is 6.0.3.

Comment: Are you running the notebook through some IDE? Running the code in directly in the web interface should work (worked for me)

Comment: @stuckonhere I am on Ubuntu and ran jupyter with the command `jupyter notebook` from the Telegram. My current jupyter notebook version is 6.0.3